Enable the older uGUI on Unity
I'm doing a Unity course that uses uGUI to create the HUD, but my current Unity version don't have that option to add Canvas, text and etc, just the UI Toolkit, that I didn't like to use; so, how can I enable the uGUI to still creating using it?
Here's an image with just the UI Toolit available.


Open the package manager Window -> Package Manager and in the top left corner of the window, switch to "Unity Registry".

Scroll down to the item "Unity UI" and install.

